# Privacy of .gitignore when pushing or cloning repositories?

Tags: git

When I push my local repository to a remote repository, my local .gitignore file will be pushed to the remote as well.

When someone clones my repository, they will copy my .gitignore file as well.

The files I put inside .gitignore might be private, so are the names of the files. So I wonder if it is a good idea that my .gitignore file is pushed or copied into a different repository?  Generally, is .gitignore file supposed to be private itself?

Can we make it not pushable or clonable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For private excludes you can use `.git/info/exclude` which has the same syntax and, basically, works the same way, but is not stored in the repository.

Also there is `core.excludesFile` (see `man git-config`) for your own *global* (that is, not per-repository) excludes.

Comment: Thanks. I want to emphasize that the purpose of using .gitignore file is to prevent certain files be pushed or cloned into another repository. So do you mean that, by using `.git/info/exclude`, I will prevent those files be committed into my local repository, and therefore not pushed or cloned into other repositories?

Comment: @Tim Yes, exactly. As I said it works exactly the same way as `.gitignore`, so if the names of the files are private, you better use `.git/info/exclude`. If you also happen to have those files in a number of repositories, using global ignore file might be more convenient.

Comment: but what if i want my local repository to include the files that I want to prevent pushing to other repositories?

Comment: @Tim That’s impossible. Your commits either include those files or they do not. You could setup a push hook that will do `git filter-branch` to remove those files from all the commits before pushing the commits to a remote, but then you won’t be able to pull anything back from that remote, since it will have _different_ commits.

Comment: thanks. When you said `.git/info/exclude` is not stored in the repository, do you mean this file is ignored in the local repository?

Comment: @Tim As someone else explained to you in comments to another answer, the `.git` directory holds internal (local) structures needed for your repository to work. Its contents just can not be version controlled. You can think that Git always ignores this special `.git` directory in your working directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not `git add` your `.gitignore` file, it won't be part of the index, and hence, never be pushed to a remote.

The fact that you push your `.gitignore` file means that you added it -- I don't even think `git add --all` does that by default; so, basically, it's your fault for manually adding it in the first place.

Comment: `git add --all` updates the index to match the working directory, that is, it adds _all_ the new files. Really all. Including `.gitignore`, if it exists.

Comment: I don't list specific files to `git add`, but use shell file expansion `git add *`, because there are too many files to list explicitly. That's why .gitignore is pushed. (1) Is it possible to specify `.gitignore` inside `.gitignore` itself, in order to prevent `.gitignore` to be pushed or cloned?

Comment: @Tim It is possible, but it doesn’t make much sense. `.gitignore` is specifically for ignores that are meant to be version-controlled. So if you don’t want them to be version-controlled, you should put them elsewhere.

Comment: @k: what do you mean by ".gitignore is specifically for ignores that are meant to be version-controlled"?  Does "ignores" mean `.gitignore`, or the files listed in `.gitignore`?

Comment: @Tim By “ignores” I mean patterns that tell git which files to ignore. `.gitignore` _is meant to_ be added to the repository and pushed so that others could see it and use.

Comment: @Tim See `man gitignore` for an explanation of the different ignore files and their purpose.

Comment: @k: why ".gitignore is meant to be added to the repository and pushed so that others could see it and use"? Especially why do i want "others could see it and use"?

Comment: @Tim What do you mean “why”? Because the authors of Git decided that such a file would be useful and then they decided to call it `.gitignore`.

Comment: @k: I meant why does one want "others see and use" his `.gitignore`, i.e. let others know what files they have been prevented to pull or clone?

Comment: @Tim People usually list there binaries or other temporary files that are generated by their build systems, IDEs, programs during runtime, etc..

Answer (score 1):

> When I push my local repository to a remote repository, my local .gitignore file will be pushed to the remote as well.

This is true only if you add your `.gitignore` to your repository.

You can, of course, add `.gitignore` to your `.gitignore` file and your `.gitignore` file will *itself* be ignored.

Comment: Is it correct that both `.gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude` may or may not be stored (i.e. tracked) in my local repository. They are  only if I add them to my repository?

Comment: `.gitignore` *may* be stored in the repository (but again, you can either ignore it or simply not add it).  `.git/info/exclude` *may not* be stored in the repository.  It is local to your repo.

Comment: (1) ".git/info/exclude may not be stored in the repository". Do you mean it is not possible, or not recommended? (2) Is the whole `.git` directory the repository? If not, which part of `.git` is, and which part isn't?

Comment: It's not possible.  The (entire) `.git` directory *is* your repository, and things beneath it cannot be added or committed.

Comment: Thanks. If `.git` is my repository, then why ".git/info/exclude may not be stored in the repository"? Things under `.git` are already stored in the repository, so there is no need to add and commit them again?

Comment: Because it's *the actual repository* - the databases, the structure of the repository, the storage.  It's not *the working directory* where you check out files and work on them.  You can't add or commit things that are inside the repository directory (with all the databases).

Comment: When  `.gitignore` is added and committed, both `.gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude` are in the repository `.git`. Are they both version controlled? Why are they not both cloned when cloning the repository?

Comment: No, they are not.  `.gitignore` is in the repository in the sense that *it's checked in*.  `.git/info/exclude` is *not* in the repository in that sense.  It is never checked in.  Never committed.  It is only locally in the `.git` directory which happens *to contain the database information`.  Remember that git is a DVCS and as such you have a complete copy of the repository information and history.  All that is stored in the `.git` directory.  But that doesn't mean that the `.git` directory is checked in.  It couldn't be; that's where *the checked in data* is stored.

Comment: is it correct that a committed `.gitignore` is a blob, while `.git/info/exclude` isn't ablob? What is the latter?

Comment: It's a configuration file.  It's not a blob, because a blob is an object checked in to the repository.